# Excel: Potential Name Match

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I've been trying to create a file to track potential repeat customers without them having membership/serial numbers. If Names in Column A is a match or partial match with names in Column C.

I've managed to get it work when I insert this formula but it is only if the spelling and order of the name is an exact match.

```
=SUMPRODUCT(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(A32,$C$2:$C$15))*1)>0
```

What I am trying to achieve but cannot figure out, is how to write the formula so that:

(1) It can also identify in Column B as YES, if the order of the name in Column A is not the same as Column C.

(2) If at least 2 words in a cell within Column A matches Column C.

[[image: sample from spreadsheet]

Comment: have you tried replacing the search function with match?

Comment: Yes, which the formula works to match the names if they are in the same order. Sometimes customers enter online bookings and invert their first and last names, so I am finding a formula that can achieve that.

Comment: use mid() and find() to separate the parts of the name then use OR()...

Comment: Hi Solar Mike, it doesn't work too. I've added a screenshot to help me explain what I am trying to achieve. Please take a look if you have time. I appreciate it very much.